# Java TCP: Buffer underflow when reading an input stream from the network

Tags: java, arrays, tcp, buffer, inputstream

I have a problem with an InputStream from a TCP Socket in Java when parsing the buffer:

```
InputStream stream = (InputStream)socket.getInputStream();
int numBytesReceived = 0;
byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[20];
while(numBytesReceived != -1) {
    
    numBytesReceived = 0;
    numBytesReceived = stream.read(tempReceive);

    // Code to start reading bytes from the receiveBuffer and parse into messages here
}
```

Let's assume each message we parse from the buffer contains one header byte indicating the size of the data in the message in bytes, and the rest are the data bytes.

From the code above, the receiveBuffer is allocated for **20 bytes**. Here's an example:
[**2**,1,1,**3**,1,1,1,**4**,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

In this example we have 3 messages (I've bolded each header byte):

- One message contains a header of 2, with 2 data bytes [**2**,1,1]
- The second message contains a header of 3, so 3 data bytes [**3**,1,1,1]
- Third message contains a header of 4, so 4 data bytes [**4**,1,1,1,1]

The rest of the buffer are just 0's. This is fine until the user starts spamming a bunch of packets, so a receiveBuffer may look like this:

[**2**,1,1,**3**,1,1,1,**4**,1,1,1,1,**2**,1,1,**3**,1,1,1,**2**]

In this case, there are 6 messages, but the 6th message is cutoff. My code is going to attempt to read 2 bytes that don't exist and I get a **BufferUnderflowException** thrown.

What can I do to make sure on each **read()**, it reads all of my messages I've sent in one go at a time? I'm not sure why it's cutting off messages.

If I find a way to get all bytes in one go, then it doesn't really avoid users who spam hundreds to thousands of messages at a time, I'll have an extremely large buffer, so I need to keep the buffer size limited (assuming I ever send max 20 bytes per message)

Comment: The problem is not clear (at least to me). Is the problem that (in the second case) you are reading too much, but you wanted only three messages? Or are you asking how to handle inputs whose messages have more than 20 bytes?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I've managed to fix it. I just have to keep reading the cutoff message on the next stream read iteration. Posted my detailed answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get past this problem by simply continuing to read() on the next loop iteration if the message gets cutoff (if we're not done reading all bytes of the message).

If a message gets cutoff like shown in the example, it continues onto the next read() and I just need to check if I was previously reading a message before I parse it.